# Aligning a textarea besides several vertically aligned input elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

As shown in the image below, I would like to align a text area besides the vertically aligned several input elements. I am using bootstrap grid to achieve the required effect. 
Currently, when I use "form-horizontal", all the items stack up in a single column, hence, the **textarea** lies under the **phone input element**.

I want it to be responsive. If I use margin property on the text area, then the inputs overlap each other and so, makes the UI look messy. It would be great if I could get your help.

Desired layout:
[image: Form design]

Current layout:
[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="NAME">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-0"> 
          <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="PHONE">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-0">
            <textarea class="form-control message" rows="6" id="comment" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>          
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by [nesting columns](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). Create two columns (equal to 12 columns), then place another `row` inside each along with your columns that contain the form inputs. I imagine you want your input to use the entire space available so set the nested columns to `col-*-12` so they utilize the entire parent columns width.

**Working Example:** *Open at FullPage*

```css
form {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px 20px 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="NAME">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="E-MAIL">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="tel" placeholder="PHONE">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control message" rows="6" id="comment" placeholder="MESSAGE"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @vanburen. It really helped me to get what I wanted. Also, I could solve a couple other problems with grid nesting. Stackoverflow is a wonderful gift to humanity. :)